# Can't send links in mails sended from PHP GAE using mail API

Tags: email, google-app-engine

I have an applications running in Google App Engine for PHP. Users can register and then they receive a link to confirm registration.

This was working fine until february 14, 2016. After then, emails that contain links are not sended and no error nor exception is triggered.

This is the code i use to send the email. Nothing has changed in the application for months. Mails sended from a contact form page that uses the same function are delivered ok except those that contain a link in the body (Ex: www.anything.com). If i separate links with spaces, for example, then mails are sended normally (www .anything .com)

```
function sendMail($to, $subject, $textBody) {
    $result = true;
    $mail_options = [
        "sender" => "yyyy@zzzz.appspotmail.com",
        "to" => $to,
        "subject" => $subject,
        "textBody" => $textBody
    ];

    try {
        $message = new Message($mail_options);
        $message->send();
    } catch (InvalidArgumentException $e) {
        $result = false;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Emails are not received in spam folder neither so it seems that are not sended.
Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: can you check if the difference is the presence in the msg body of a link to the app's `appspot.com` domain or not?

Comment: there's a custom domain attached to this site so msg link does not contain appspot anywhere, is something like: http://www.ciplayer.com/?CODE. Tried with some other test domains and result is always the same. Thanks.